# Regular Group Actions and Functions

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, equivariant-maps

An action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ is **regular** if for any $x,x'\in X$, there exists a unique $g\in G$ with $gx=x'$.

(a) Give an example.

(b) Let $X$ be a set and let $G$ be a group which acts regularly on $X$. Find all maps $f:X\to X$ such that for every $x\in X$ and $g\in G$, $f(gx)=gf(x)$.

Comment: For surjectivity, choose any $y\in X$ and let $x\prime = f(x)$ then $\exists g\in G s.t. g x\prime = y$

Comment: You didn't define an $ x $

Comment: A counterexample to your guess: If $G = X = S_3$, and $G$ acts by left multiplication, then left multiplication by $(1 2)$ is a bijection $f:X \rightarrow X$, yet $(1 2) gx = g (1 2)x$ is not true for all $x$ and $g$ in $S_3$. (Any nonabelian group causes problems for the guess.)

Comment: That's an interesting example! Any idea on what else it imposes then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $x_0 \in X$ and define a map $G \rightarrow X$ by $g \rightarrow gx_0$, the regular condition implies that this is a bijection, moreover it is $G$ equivariant for the action of $G$ on itself by left multiplication. So from now on I will just assume $X = G$

One obvious source of maps $G \rightarrow G$ that commute with left multiplication are those coming from right multiplication as associativity $g(xh)= (gx)h$ is exactly the $G$ equivariance condition.  I think these should be all such maps but at the moment I can't prove it.

Edit:  after reading rogerl's answer, I see these must be all such maps as there is a unique right multiplication map sending the identity to any given element.

Comment: @Jin Since $X\cong G$ are isomorphic as $G$-sets we can without loss of generality take $X=G$; that' what Nate said. And the equivariance condition is $g(xh)=(gx)h$ just like Nate said; your second comment is very wrong.

Comment: @Nate I understand part of what you said, thanks for the details. However, I still don't get why you can assume $X=G$.

Comment: The map I defined in the first paragraph tells us that there is, up to renaming of elements, exactly one regular (left) action of $G$, the action of $G$ on itself. In slightly different language, this shows that any such $X$ must be isomorphic to $G$ as objects in the category of left $G$-sets. In particular, in any category the set of endomorphisms (which is what these functions are) is an invariant of the isomorphism class, so it is fine to just do the calculation for a single choice of such object.

Comment: @Nate Thanks for the comment. After having read more about it, I understand your answer!

Answer (score 2):

I think these functions are bijective with $X$. Choose some base point $x_0\in X$, and let $f(x_0) = x_0'$. Then if $x\in X$, we have $x = gx_0$ for a unique $g$; the equivariance condition then gives $f(x) = f(gx_0) = gf(x_0) = gx_0'$. So the function $f$ is determined by its value at any element of $X$.

Comment: This is cool, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As for (a), every group $G$ acts regularly on itself by left multiplication. In fact, for every $h,k\in G$, there is a unique $g:=kh^{-1}\in G$ such that:
$$gh=k$$
Yet another example: for $p$ a prime, $\operatorname{Aut}(C_p)$ acts regularly on the set of the
generators of $C_p$.